# Rename a file based on a selection list

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, rename, list, vb.net

I have to rename thousands of image files with a set of name list such as photos of products named as `topview`, `topview1`, `topview2`, etc., and `sideview`, `sideview1`, ..., `sideviewn`, `backview`, `frontview1234`, etc. So I want to automate this work by creating a special folder named as product name and copy all the images of that product into it. I want to rename images in this folder like this: whenever I choose an image and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename (thumbnail view of course) it will appear a drop down list of preset name list (or dialog window, etc.) such as `topview`, `sideview`, `frontview`, `backview` and an option of typing new name if not preset in the list, if `topview` is taken before then the next picking on `topview` will create new name `topview1` then `topview2` `topviewn`, etc.

I don't know the code that Windows rename a file by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> so I try another way, I code a Windows application form based on vb.net through Visual Studio but I'm stucking with my code. Please give me some advice to make it work. 
My code include running code and designer code as follows:

Running code:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        If New Global.System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog() With {
            .Title = "Select a file",
            .InitialDirectory = "D:\TestRen",
            .Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*",
            .FilterIndex = 2,
            .RestoreDirectory = True
        }.ShowDialog() = Global.System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim strFilename As String = New OpenFileDialog() With {
            .Title = "Select a file",
            .InitialDirectory = "D:\TestRen",
            .Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*",
            .FilterIndex = 2,
            .RestoreDirectory = True
        }.FileName
            'get extension
            Dim extn As String = Path.GetExtension(strFilename)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim var As String
        var = ComboBox1.Text
        'It is stucking at this rename syntax
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(strFilename, var + extn)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Designer code:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.ComboBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.Button2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.Button3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.Button4 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'ComboBox1
        '
        Me.ComboBox1.FormattingEnabled = True
        Me.ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"Front view", "Back view", "Left view", "Right view"})
        Me.ComboBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(15, 112)
        Me.ComboBox1.Name = "ComboBox1"
        Me.ComboBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(309, 21)
        Me.ComboBox1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(370, 112)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 1
        Me.Button1.Text = "Rename"
        Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Button2
        '
        Me.Button2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(370, 166)
        Me.Button2.Name = "Button2"
        Me.Button2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.Button2.TabIndex = 2
        Me.Button2.Text = "Next"
        Me.Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Button3
        '
        Me.Button3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(370, 239)
        Me.Button3.Name = "Button3"
        Me.Button3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.Button3.TabIndex = 3
        Me.Button3.Text = "Cancel"
        Me.Button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Button4
        '
        Me.Button4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(370, 57)
        Me.Button4.Name = "Button4"
        Me.Button4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.Button4.TabIndex = 6
        Me.Button4.Text = "Select a file"
        Me.Button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(488, 312)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button4)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button3)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.ComboBox1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Select a name"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents ComboBox1 As ComboBox
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As Button
    Friend WithEvents Button2 As Button
    Friend WithEvents Button3 As Button
    Friend WithEvents Button4 As Button
End Class
```

My design is like this: click button4 (Select a file) to pick a file name in a folder to get input of *oldname* and the combobox for *newname* then click button1 (Rename) to rename file, after a successful process the Next button will do the loop to get next input, the Cancel button to exit application when all done. It need more many codes to get my all targets but I want to understand the key process (rename in vb.net) to go further.